# Tools to detect programs that are used infrequently or are never used

Tags: windows, performance

Is there a Windows tool that would detect programs that are used infrequently or are never used? It would help cleaning up unwanted programs and cluttered Windows.

Comment: Win7, Win8 or XP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with a `last used` or `(in)frequently used` is that it is pretty much impossible to make it accurate. Windows does not track every file a program 'installs'; it is up to the programs' own installer to do so. The program then registers an entry in the program list (*only* if it wants), with a link to its own uninstaller. Arguably, installers created with Windows Installer could expose more information and are more centrally managed, but it is still possible for programs to dump files wherever.

What constitutes use? Is it when the main executable is run? When any associated file is touched? When the settings that live in the user profile are modified? Remember that it is not necessary to 'run' a file to 'read' it; for example an antivirus program scanning a file could be counted as 'use'.

The method I described below apparently has been disabled since XP (where the column appears to be enabled by default), and was never reliable anyway.

---

I'm not sure what exactly defines 'used', but the `Uninstall or change a program` window (at least on Windows 8, I'd expect back to Vista if not XP) does have a column with such a heading.

1. Open `Uninstall or change a program`, either via the Control Panel or Start Menu/Screen search.
2. Right click on a column heading. Select `More...`

   [image]
3. Tick `Last Used On`

   [image]
4. You can now click on the new column heading to sort ascending or descending.

Comment: +1 for "What constitutes use?"

Answer (score 0):

Windows already has a tool like this embedded. If you go to control panel and then go to applications you will see a list with the installed apps and a column at the right will show you how often the app has been used.

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old post, but I just covered this in one of my classes on Computers for my clients. Hoping this helps future folks!

**http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/**

- TreeSize Free is freeware for Windows XP and upwards.

..........Users of Windows 2000 can download the last compatible version (TreeSize Free V2.4) here.
..........Users of Windows 9x/ME can download the last compatible version (TreeSize Free V2.1) here.

*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*

**http://www.mindgems.com/products/Folder-Size/Folder-Size.html**

- Operating system: Windows 10/Windows 8.1/Windows 8/Windows 7/Windows Vista/Windows XP/Windows NT/Windows ME/Windows 2000/Windows 2003/Windows 98/

I spent all last year working on different freewares and these "Last Accessed" are spot on..... on my XP and MediaCenter versions.

Anelle

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. Treesize/FolderSize does not show when programs were last used.